# Prevent Spring bean re-initialization for each JUnit test

Tags: java, spring, junit, integration-testing, liquibase

I have integration tests based on JUnit that access DB. We also use Liquibase Spring bean to init database.

If I try running multiple tests in parallel each of them tries to initialize DB using Liquibase causing locks and eventually failures since only one instance of Liquibase can modify DB at a time.

The tests are configured as follows:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@Transactional
@WebAppConfiguration
@Sql({"/schema/insert-test-data.sql"})
```

How can I configure DB initialization (schema and data) that it will be done only once and not for each test?

Comment: Well, that's the whole point about unit tests: they must act (and be executed independently) as a single, atomic unit. In your case, you want a hybrid...and in that realm, you would need to have an instance of your database running beforehand, and finally committing (or not) the transaction's modification(s).

Comment: If they run in parallel everything should be separated including the database or you need to have a prefilled database and take care of not modifying data (i.e. rollback everything) else you will into issues with your tests as one tests influences the other.

Comment: @M.Deinum All tests run in transactions and rolled back, so this part works fine. My question is how to do DB initialization so it will be performed only once.

Answer (score 0):

This is just idea not testet, but if you are not executing scripts in parallel what about using [ScriptUtils](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/init/ScriptUtils.html) or [ResourceDatabasePopulator](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/init/ResourceDatabasePopulator.html) iside `@Before` method with some switch.

```
@Before
public void init(){
    if (wasInitialized)
        return;

    new ResourceDatabasePopulator(new ClassPathResource("path/to/sql.sql")).execute(dataSource);
    wasInitialized = true;
}
```